# How to calculate the standard deviation for every 100 points in a nx3 vector?

Tags: matlab, standard-deviation

Suppose I have a matrix with *n* rows, each containing three coordinates, (x, y and z). I want to calculate the standard deviation for every 100 set of points in MATLAB. For example, for the first 100 x coordinates I apply [`std`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html), then same for the y and z coordinates, and so on... eventually I have one set of x, y and z values for every 100 points. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: I feel like I may misinterpret the size of your matrix, but either way it should not be too hard to get a working solution based on my answer.

Comment: So there is a LOT of data, I could try running it separately. So for example the first set has about 3000 sets of points.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of using reshape or ndgrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
M = randn(120,3); % substitute this for the actual data; 3 columns
N = 100; % number of elements in each set for which std is computed

cols = size(A,1);
for n = 1:ceil(cols/N)
  row_ini = (n-1)*N+1;
  row_fin = min(n*N, cols); % the "min" is in case cols is not a multiple of N
  std(A(row_ini:row_fin,:))
end
```

The "for" loop could probably be vectorized, if speed is a concern.

Edit: If you want to store all results in a three-column matrix, you just modify the "std" line and add some initialization, like this:

```
M = randn(120,3); % substitute this for the actual data; 3 columns
N = 100; % number of elements in each set for which std is computed

cols = size(A,1);
n_max = ceil(cols/N);
result = repmat(NaN,ceil(cols/N),3); % initialize
for n = 1:n_max
  row_ini = (n-1)*N+1;
  row_fin = min(n*N, cols); % the "min" is in case cols is not a multiple of N
  result(n,:) = std(A(row_ini:row_fin,:));
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! one last question- To store all these in one new vector where do I include it? Lets say I want it all in one 3 x n vector? Or if I then want to take the mean of every row to result in a 1 x n vector?

Comment: I have posted a modified solution to do this

Comment: @LuisMendo You should consider editing the new solution into this answer instead of posting it as a separate one.

Comment: +1 For challenging the `for` loop taboo in order to get a solid readable answer. A great way to start Overflowing!